# Firefox XUL Toolbar background image

Tags: css, firefox-addon, xul

I have my own toolbar with toolbox and toolbarpalette.
I have followed this https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Skinning_XUL_Files_by_Hand
and background image for toolbar is not displaying, what can be wrong?
Cannot found any debug message in Error console

Note that **Image #logoimage is displaying correctly**

**XUL**

```
<toolbox id="navigator-toolbox" class="nav-box" crop="end">
        <toolbarpalette id="BrowserToolbarPalette">
            <image id="logoimage"/>
            <toolbarbutton type="menu" label="&toolbar.quicklinks.label;" id="quicklinks">
                <menupopup>
                    <menuitem class="menuitem-iconic" label="&toolbar.quicklinks.quicklink1;" image="chrome://tbar/skin/icon.png"/>
                </menupopup>
            </toolbarbutton>
        </toolbarpalette>
        <toolbar id="test-toolbar"
             class="nav-bar"
             mode="full"
             iconsize="small"
             customizable="true"
             context="toolbar-context-menu"
             toolbarname="Toolbar"
             crop="end"
             defaultset="logoimage,toolbarseparator,quicklinks">
        </toolbar>
    </toolbox>
```

**CSS**

```
toolbar.nav-bar {
    background-image: url("chrome://tbar/skin/tbg.png");
}

#logoimage {
    list-style-image: url("chrome://tbar/skin/logo.png");
}
```

Comment: This shouldn't be related but why are you styling your toolbar by class name rather than ID? `#test-toolbar` would make more sense as a selector (and it would be faster).

Comment: this is related to link I posted on top of my question, they suggest to use class-name, so I tried, but using ID or DOM/CSS path doesn't make any difference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As nobody could help, I asked in mozilla.dev.tech.xul Google group, and got an answer

> Try adding "**-moz-appearance: none;**" to your CSS stanza. This turns off 
>   OS-defined theming.

And that thing simply worked ! It also removes all OS specific look and feel effects

see: https://groups.google.com/group/mozilla.dev.tech.xul/browse_thread/thread/a4cd4452a72b9151#

Answer (score 1):

Given that there are no issues in the code you show here I only see one explanation: the background image is being set to a different value elsewhere, maybe in some built-in CSS file. You can check the CSS rules applying to a particular UI element using [DOM Inspector](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/dom-inspector-6622/).

Comment: no, you're not right, tried with setting `color` property and it changed right there on toolbar, not anywhere else

Comment: @Marek: No problem - if you downvote answers instead of reading them then I don't need to answer your questions.

Comment: oh, I've read your answer. You haven't answered why it doesn't work (what I asked for). Your suggestion about DOM Inspector is good, but as I said, I tried more rules, and only `background-image` is not applying.

Answer (score 1):

Does your toolbar have a height and width? I can't remember if they're block by default, but it might not be showing because it has no dimensions?

Comment: even if i specify dimensions, color is not applied. and so, I can't (or I don't know) how to make it 100% width.